# In LCD/LED displays, does the back light strobe or remain on?

Tags: led, lcd, backlight

In LCD/LED displays, like the ones used with computers or for watching TV channels. Does the back light strobe in sync with the refresh rate or does it remain on all the time?

Comment: That varies. Constant on would be common though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the backlight will remain steady all the time.

There is such a thing as color sequential LCDs that strobe backlight, but they are not common.

[Here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm36273.pdf) is a modern LCD backlight driver chip. The ripple voltage at the output is only a few tens of mV which will result in very little ripple current.

Don't be confused by the PWM mentions in that datasheet, that refers to an input into the driver chip that is used to program the output current as an alternative to I2C.

Comment: By generally do you mean most of the time? In that case, is there any time when they might strobe?

Comment: I can't rule out that there might be such a design, but they don't appear to be very common in my experience. There are some display backlights designed to dim locally to improve dynamic range, and they would vary with display content.